# Creating a WordPress-like permalinks rewrite/redirect using PHP and .htaccess, is it possible?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've been working on a module for a PHP-based application that would allow users to create custom pages. These pages have a URL structure as follows:

> yourdomain.com/page.php?url=random-slug

I would like to have these URLs rewritten to use a more SEO-friendly approach:

> yourdomain.com/random-slug/

In addition, there should two (2) redirects that accompany this rewrite:

> yourdomain.com/page.php?url=random-slug => yourdomain.com/random-slug/

> yourdomain.com/random-slug => yourdomain.com/random-slug/

Would this be possible? If so, what would the .htaccess (Apache) file look like to accomplish this? I have tried the following for the rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)?.php$ ./page.php?url=$1 [L,NC]
```

Unfortunately, the above also seems to break other links on the site as well. I'm not exactly sure why yet but was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

Thank you for your help!

---

Edit:

I was able to find a way to accomplish this with the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.*?)/?$ ./page.php?url=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /page\.php\?url=([^\&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^/?page\.php$ ./%1/? [R=301, L]
```

Hopefully this will help anyone else with a similar request :)

Comment: Why do you need `yourdomain.com/page.php?url=random-slug => yourdomain.com/random-slug/`? Your current rule sets `$_GET['url']` so you can work with that, but your first desire will to opposte

Comment: Just to understand, if I set the redirect I'll lose the ability to get the URL via slug? My thought on redirecting the non-SEO friendly URL was so that Google doesn't think it's duplicate content.

Comment: When you set `slug -> queryString` convert, you can then access both `/slug` and `?url=slug`. In most cases it's ok, since all your links should be using only `/slug` and only manually you can enter `?url=slug`

Comment: I can't guarantee that will always happen. Since this is a product for the end-user, they could put the non-SEO friendly links in their site. I wanted to find a way to help avoid that if possible.

Comment: From my experience you put some URL formatting before outputing links, so it is always in SEO-friendly format.

Comment: Thanks, @Justinas for the feedback! I was able to find something that worked well for me :)